# ¿Como puedo obtener la información de un Stream?

Tags: c#, webservice, pdf, servicio, stream

Podrían ayudarme por favor con este tema, tengo un método que me devuelve un stream como pueden ver en la imagen, es un pdf, cuando consulto el servicio en los miembros no públicos en el atributo message me llega el pdf en base64 pero no he podido obtener la información que me llega en el Stream, en la imagen pueden ver el código que uso pero la respuesta en el txt es NULL.

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda, he buscado por todos lados y no he podido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la imagen veo un `Envelope` y eso se relaciona a un mensaje `SOAP`, pero si es asi no tiene nada que ver con un `Stream`. Que servicio estas invocando? y porque dices que es un stream cuando en realidad no deberia serlo, sino que deberias obtener un class que crea el proxy de web service

Comment: Este es el método, el tipo de retorno es  Stream, el webservice es un SOAP que tengo agregado como referencia, tienes un ejemplo de una manera diferente como puedo obtener la data. gracias

´´public System.IO.Stream ConsultaPDFAutorizadoByID(decimal IdComprobante) {
            return base.Channel.ConsultaPDFAutorizadoByID(IdComprobante);
        }´´

Comment: Por otro lado no sé como acceder a ese Envelope que viste ya que está en los miembros no públicos como se muestra en la imagen, ya obteniendo ese Envelope podría guardar el pdf sin problema ya que allí está el pdf en base64

Comment: algo no cierra, si obtienes un stream de donde salen las propiedades que nos muestras en la ultima imagen? que objeto inspeccionas para ver esas propiedades?

Comment: `Stream prueba = client.ConsultaPDFAutorizadoByID(20924355832930001);`

Ese es el llamado que realizo, en debug inspecciono la variable prueba e ingreso a los miembros no públicos en debug.

Comment: Aunque has recibido comentarios y una respuesta de un consagrado como @LeandroTuttini con más de 33 mil de reputación, yo que solo soy un humilde aprendiz en este sitio y en la programación, te digo que es regla en este sitio que el código se debe colocar en texto, nunca en imágenes; de tal forma que a quien te quiera ayudar, le sea menos trabajoso, revisar e incluso poder probar el código que va a colocar en su respuesta, eso es algo de lógica elemental, pues si estas pidiendo una ayuda, no es elegante, hacer que quien te vaya a ayudar tenga que teclear incluso tu propio código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias grabar el archivo usando

```
Stream prueba = client.ConsultaPDFAutorizadoByID(20924355832930001);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    prueba.CopyTo(stream);
    File.WriteAllBytes("hola.pdf", stream.ToArray());
}
```

pero lo que vas a generar es un `.pdf` ya que estas guardando el `byte[]` no el `base64`, no se puede abrir con el `notepad`, necesitas un `pdf reader`.

Si quieres tener los `base64` en un archivo de texto, entonces seria:

```
Stream prueba = client.ConsultaPDFAutorizadoByID(20924355832930001);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    prueba.CopyTo(stream);
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    File.WriteAllText("hola.txt", base64);
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, es la solución que estaba buscando, te debo una, mil gracias de nuevo